# use Java command in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use java command in laravel project but I get error "'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
please help me

```
 $process = new Process(['java','-cp', 'weka.jar weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans', '-T', $path.'unseen.arff', '-l', $path.'Tourist.model']);
        $process->run();
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }
        $output = $process->getOutput();
```

Comment: Is Java installed? Try using the absolute path to the Java binary

Comment: You are trying to call a Java jar file from PHP, you need a PHPBridge to access the java file. Here: https://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a Java jar file from PHP, you need a PHPBridge to access the java file. Here: [PHP Java Bridge](https://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/)